# What is a name for statistical indicators such as GDP annual rate, unemployment rate?

Tags: hypernyms, lexicon

I have a question regarding the common general name of statistical indicators such as GDP annual rate, inflation rate, unemployment rate, etc.

For example, in the following sentence, what would fill in the blank best:

> Below there are statistical indicators for a country in three ____.

I don't know how to end the sentence. They are not fields nor groups, nothing comes to my mind as to how the statistical pointers are split, what is a GDP annual rate in this context, for example?

Comment: metrics? I don't really understand why you want to do this (it seems like repeating yourself) but it's hard to suggest an alternative without more context.

Comment: It’s not clear what groups you’re referring to.  “Shown below are three economic indicators for each country.”  And do you mean GDP ***growth*** rate?  GDP is not a rate.

Comment: I don't understand the question, but maybe the answer can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_indicator. So, your groups could be leading/lagging/coincident or procyclical/countercyclical/acyclical.

Comment: Hi Teva, it is unclear what level of abstraction you are talking about. It sounds like you are referring to a figure or graph. Why isn't 'indicator' the right word? If not, why not 'group'? Do you have a word for this in your native language (if so, please give that, it might help). Also, in the end, this may be a very particular technical term in economics, that people in economics will know about much better.

Comment: Perhaps ". . . in three **contexts**" or ". . . in three **areas**".

Comment: I don't have a word for it in my language. I am reffering to GDP growth rate, inflation rate and unemployemnt rate, these are only three economical indicators ( I am talking about one specific country), so I wanted to understand what these rates "are". The last comment from Vane was on the right track only I don't know if you could say that inflation rate is area.

Comment: @IevaBrakmane Surely, these three economic indicators are called "economic indicators"? I think you have got an over complex sentence by already referring to statistical indicators when introducing the same statistical indicators. So your example sentence could be something like: "Below are three economic indicators for a country." (You could replace "indicators" with "metrics".)

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking that these indicators cover three different ***aspects*** of the economy?